# Pre-processing data: Normalizing data labels in regression?

Tags: machine-learning, regression, normalization

Recently I was told that the labels of regression data should also be normalized for better result but I am pretty doubtful of that. I have never tried normalizing labels in both regression and classification that's why I don't know if that state is true or not. Can you please give me a clear explanation (mathematically or in experience) about this problem?

Thank you so much. 
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Where were you told this? I've never heard it before and it fact it doesn't make any intuitive sense. The labels themselves are not used in any regression calculation that I know of.

Comment: @JamieBull a senior of mine told me that. I feel it's very absurd so I want to make sure about that. Also I want to have a solid explanation to tell him why it's unnecessary to perform it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say "normalize" labels, it is not clear what you mean (i.e. whether you mean this in a statistical sense or something else). Can you please provide an example?

On **Making labels uniform in data analysis**
If you are trying to neaten labels for use with the `text()` function, you could try the `abbreviate()` function to shorten them, or the `format()` function to align them better.

The `pretty()` function works well for rounding labels on plot axes. For instance, the base function `hist()` for drawing histograms calls on Sturges or other algorithms and then uses `pretty()` to choose nice bin sizes.

The `scale()` function will standardize values by subtracting their mean and dividing by the standard deviation, which in some circles is referred to as normalization.

**On the reasons for scaling in regression** (in response to comment by questor). Suppose you regress Y on covariates X1, X2, ... The reasons for scaling covariates Xk depend on the context. It can enable comparison of the coefficients (effect sizes) of each covariate. It can help ensure numerical accuracy (these days not usually an issue unless covariates on hugely different scales and/or data is big). For a readable intro see [Psychosomatic medicine editors' guide](http://stattips.blogspot.com.au/2009/08/rescaling-continuous-predictors-in.html). For a mathematically intense discussion see [Sylvain Sardy's guide](http://www.unige.ch/math/folks/sardy/Papers/rescaling.pdf).

In particular, in Bayesian regression, rescaling is advisable to ensure convergence of MCMC estimation; e.g. see [this discussion](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/29781/when-conducting-multiple-regression-when-should-you-center-your-predictor-varia).

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Normalization here means scaling data by using any scaling techniques (range 0-1 or subtracting mean and dividing by standard deviation). And I need an explanation why I should/shouldn't do that for data labels in regression, not specific functions to do it.

Comment: For example the data labels of regression problem can be float numbers in the range of 1-5. My question is whether I should scale them into the range of 0-1 or not.

Comment: Ah. Scaling data "labels" is unorthodox terminology. However **scaling data** is more standard ... I have edited my answer to include links.

Comment: Answers so far would benefit greatly if you could provide an example of what _you_ mean by data "labels" from a classification and/or regression, _e.g._ referring to output from `lm()` or `cluster()` in R. See guidelines on minimum working examples.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. Actually I need a simple answer like this http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/111467/is-it-necessary-to-scale-the-target-value-in-addition-to-scaling-features-for-re
Some guys already helped me find the answer. Thank you very much anyway.

Comment: This indicates that your question should have been "Do I need to rescale my response (sometimes called a dependent) variable in a regression?" rather than anything about data labels. The answer to that question is NO! This is a common misconception in new (and sometimes experienced) users of regression - **the response variable need not be norma**l. If fitting a regression with normally distributed errors, then **it is the errors (aka residuals) that you need to check for normality**. In the 1960s, analysts used to normalize their responses

Comment: [Continuing previous comment] as a klunky computational approximation. **However, this "normalization" is no longer necessary since the invention of Generalized Linear Models (GLMs) which allow you to fit regressions with non-normal responses**. Try Poisson or Negative Binomial regression for count responses. Try Binomial/logistic/probit regression for binary responses like true/false or present/absent. There are many other distributional choices for the responses. **And none of these require normalization of the response data.**

Comment: thank you very much. Your explanations are very detailed and intuitive.

Answer (score 2):

It may be that what you mean is that you should *scale* your labels. The reason is so convergence is faster, and you don't get numeric instability.

For example, if your labels are in the range (1000, 1000000) and the weights are initialized close to zero, a mse loss would be so large, you'd likely get NaN errors.

See https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/22776/38707 for a similar discussion.

Answer (score 1):

You mean features not labels.

It is not necessary to normalize your features for regression or classification, even though in some cases, it is a trick that can help converging faster. You might want to check [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/41704/how-and-why-do-normalization-and-feature-scaling-work).

To my experience, when using a simple model like a linear regression with only a few variables, keeping the features as they are (without normalization) is preferable since the model is more interpretable.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I really meant data LABELS, not features because feature normalization is already a familiar technique and there are already many articles about it.

Comment: Ok, sorry about that. I have never heard about such a thing and I don't see the point of normalizing labels. The following post explains why it does not have any impact: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/111467/is-it-necessary-to-scale-the-target-value-in-addition-to-scaling-features-for-re. Hope it helps.

Comment: thank you very much for your help. It really is the explanation I need. I forgot that in regression, label is called target variable. Thats why I couldn't find that post. Again thank you and have a nice day!

Comment: Isn't the target variable only called a label in a classification model rather than regression?

Comment: Yes, "label" is used for classification not regression.

Answer (score 0):

for a regression problem with algorithms including decision tree or logistic regression and linear regression I tested in two modes: 1- with label scaling using MinMaxScaler 2- without label scaling the result that i got was : r2 score is the same in 2 mode mse and mae scales

for diabetes dataset using linear regression the result before and after is

**without scaling:**

```
Mean Squared Error: 3424.3166
Mean Absolute Error: 46.1742

R2_score : 0.33
```

**after scaling labels:**

```
Mean Squared Error: 0.0332
Mean Absolute Error: 0.1438
R2_score : 0.33
```

also below link can be useful which says scaling can be helpful in fast convergence enter  [scale or not scale labels in deep leaning?](https://medium.com/@pandelab/some-dangers-of-label-normalization-in-ml-6482d955882e)